# How to get the strings to print in order after they have been reversed

Tags: c++

The goal of this program is to get user input and then print the words backwards, but still in the order the user typed them in. For example, the user input- "cats and mice are cool", then the program should output "stac dna ecim era looc", but what I am getting is "looc era ecim dna stac". I think that rearranging the words would happen in the main function, but I'm not sure how to get it to print in order. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void reverse(string input) {
    int size = (int)input.size();

    if(size==1){
        cout << input[size-1];
    }
    else {
        cout << input[size-1];
        reverse(input.substr(0, size-1));
    }
}

int main() {
    string input;
    char choice;    

    cout << "Please enter a string with spaces." << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    reverse(input);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: split the string by word, print each word reversed (and add spaces in between words ofc)

Comment: How do I split it, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/5470596

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked at the link and I'm still confused. This is an assignment and there are certain things I haven't learned yet. I have to use only what library headers I am given. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're reversing the entire string... split string on spaces, then cycle on splits and call `reverse()` on every split before printing it.

Furthermore, you can use C++ STL classes for reversing and even result useful in splitting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string text, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    std::istringstream f(text);
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(f, s, delimiter)) {
        res.push_back(s);
    }

    return(res);
}

int main() {
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Please enter a string with spaces." << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    for(auto s : split(input, ' '))
    {
        std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can avoid some work by doing the split with the original `getline`. Although there are circumstances in more complex programs where you do want line-input before you do anything else